# only edit (update) fields provided by form into mongoose subdocument

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

i wanted to update my mongoose subdocument with whatever field i fill in the form its working fine but the problem i am facing is if any of the field is left empty and then i submit i want it to just update the subdocumnet with just the fields provided by the form and fields which are not provided should be left with what it was before. currently it is deleting the fields not provided by form inside subdocument after the update

this is the update fn i am currently using

```
List.updateOne(
        {"questionSet._id": questId},
        {
            $set: {
                "questionSet.$": req.body
            }
        },
        {new: true, useFindAndModify: false},
        (e)=>{
            if(e){
                console.log(e);
                res.redirect("/admin-edit-quest")
            } else {
                res.redirect("/admin-edit-quest")
            }
        }
    )
```

this is eg. of my mongoose model

```
list: { "_id" : ObjectId("60f2cc07275bbb30d8cb268e"), 
"listName" : "dsa", 
"aboutList" : "dsa queestions",
 questionSet" : [ { "solved" : false, 
                   "_id" : ObjectId("60f2cc12275bbb30d8cb2695"), 
                    "topic" : "array", 
                     "name" : "array is best", 
                    "url" : "www.arr.com", 
                       "listname" : "dsa", 
                     "__v" : 0 }, 
               { "solved" : false,  
                 "_id" : ObjectId("60f2cc1b275bbb30d8cb269d"), 
                "topic" : "linked list",
               "name" : "reverse list", 
                 "url" : "www.list.com",
                "listname" : "dsa",
                 "__v" : 0 } 
               ], 
"__v" : 2 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to delete keys with blank values from `req.body`:

```js
pruned_body = {}
body = JSON.parse(reg.body)

Object.keys(body).forEach(function (key) { 
  if (body[key]) {
    pruned_body[key] = body[key]
 }})
```

And then use `pruned_body` in  `$set`.

Comment: i have tried this method by passing req.body to a function which deletes empty key value pairs and converting it to a JS Object then i pass that object to $set but this results in deleting the key value pairs (which were not present in the object) in my mongoose documnet and if i directly pass req.body it just deletes the content inside the key value pairs for the fields which were not provided by the html form and updates the provided fields